# C++11 alias templates in CUDA

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, cuda, template-aliases

The essential question is are [alias templates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) supported by the CUDA compiler?

I am using CUDA 7.5 on Ubuntu with gcc-4.8. All of my template classes are defined in header files and `#include`d into a single translation unit during compilation.

I have a simple `cuda_array` class that provides a thin wrapper around a `std::vector`. It's essentially a very simple version of `thrust::host_vector` combined with a `thrust::device_vector`. Its declaration is

```
template <typename T, const size_t N>
class cuda_array {
    std::vector<T> host;
    T *device;
public:
    // lots of type aliases to meet container requirements
    void push() { /* cudaMemcpy(...,H2D); */ }
    void pull() { /* cudaMemcpy(...,D2H); */ }
    // a few others that aren't relevant here
};
```

To make a matrix, I just made a quick template alias.

```
template <typename T, const size_t M, const size_t N>
using cuda_matrix = cuda_array<T, M * N>;
```

I want to map my matrix-vector multiplication CUDA kernel onto the overloaded `operator*` for type safety and easy use (it is left to the caller to ensure that `push` and `pull` are called correctly).

```
template <typename T, const size_t rows, const size_t cols>
__global__ void matrix_vector_mul(T *A, T *b, T *result) {
     __shared__ T shared_b[cols];
    // rest of it
}

template <typename T, const size_t M, const size_t N>
__host__ cuda_array<T, M> operator*(cuda_matrix<T, M, N> &m, cuda_array<T, N> &v) {
    cuda_array<T, M> result;
    matrix_vector_mul<T, M, N><<<16, 32>>>(m.device_data(), v.device_data(), result.device_data());
    return result;
}
```

In my 'main.cpp', I then have

```
cuda_matrix<int,16,32> A;
cuda_array<int,32> b;
auto result = A * b;
```

The last line throws an error saying

```
error: no operator "*" matches these operands
        operand types are: cuda_matrix<int, 16UL, 32UL> * cuda_array<int, 32UL>
```

I chased down all of the usual suspects for template type deduction errors I could think of, but nothing worked. In desperation, I converted my `cuda_matrix` alias template into a template class.

```
template <typename T, const size_t M, const size_t N>
class cuda_matrix : public cuda_array<T, M * N> {};
```

And the compile error disappears! It therefore seems that CUDA does not yet support alias templates. Or did I do something silly that I can't figure out?

Comment: `M` `N` in `cuda_array<T, M * N>` are non-deducible, since are part of a subexpression, it's unrelated to CUDA whatsoever

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must remember that:

§ 14.5.7 [temp.alias]/p2:

> When a *template-id* refers to the specialization of an alias template, it is equivalent to the associated type
>   obtained by substitution of its template-arguments for the template-parameters in the *type-id* of the alias
>   template. [ *Note*: An alias template name is never deduced. — *end note* ]

This means that deduction is not performed for:

```
template <typename T, const size_t M, const size_t N>
__host__ cuda_array<T, M> operator*(cuda_matrix<T, M, N> &m, cuda_array<T, N> &v)
```

but for:

```
template <typename T, const size_t M, const size_t N>
__host__ cuda_array<T, M> operator*(cuda_array<T, M * N> &m, cuda_array<T, N> &v)
//                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

And so:

§ 14.8.2.5 [temp.deduct.type]/p16:

> If, in the declaration of a function template with a non-type template parameter, the non-type template
>   parameter is used in a subexpression in the function parameter list, **the expression is a non-deduced context**
>   as specified above.

`M` is in a non-deducible context, hence this `operator*` is not considered as a viable overload.

As one of the workarounds, you can instead verify the deduced value for `cuda_array` itself:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t MN, std::size_t N>
auto operator*(const cuda_array<T, MN>& m, const cuda_array<T, N>& v)
    -> typename std::enable_if<(MN/N)*N==MN, cuda_array<T, MN/N>>::type;
```

or use the inheritance trick that you  already have; then `M` and `N` are separate non-type template parameters of `cuda_matrix`.

Comment: I see now. I didn't know alias template types are non-deducible. Removing the CUDA-specific parts and running it through gcc-4.9 gives an error message that makes this point much clearer.